Why does the ChipGroup#getCheckedChipIds method return an empty list
I'm trying to retrieve all the chips checked in a ChipGroup. I want to use the attribute.
app:singleSelection="false". However, when I use the value false, the ChipGroup#getCheckedChipIds returns an empty list. However, when I use the value true, I get a non-empty list with the selected item as expected.
I have tried using the kotlin filter function to check if the Chips inside the ChipGroup are checked as follows
daysFilter.children.map { it as Chip }.filter {
        it.isChecked
}

However, I still get an empty list. I've tried with it.isSelected and it still returns false for all Chips inside the ChipGroup.
The layout file for the ChipGroup is as follows:
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/days_filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
    app:chipSpacingHorizontal="0dp"
    app:singleLine="true"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    tools:checkedChip="@id/friday">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/sunday"
        style="?materialFilterChipStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:text="@string/chip_choice_sun"
        app:chipEndPadding="12dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="12dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/monday"
        style="?materialFilterChipStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:text="@string/chip_choice_mon"
        app:chipEndPadding="10dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="10dp"
        app:shapeAppearance="?shapeAppearanceCornerFull" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/tuesday"
        style="?materialFilterChipStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:text="@string/chip_choice_tue"
        app:chipEndPadding="12dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="12dp"
        app:shapeAppearance="?shapeAppearanceCornerFull" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/wednesday"
        style="?materialFilterChipStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chip_choice_wed"
        app:shapeAppearance="?shapeAppearanceCornerFull" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/thursday"
        style="?materialFilterChipStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chip_choice_thu"
        app:chipEndPadding="12dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="12dp"
        app:shapeAppearance="?shapeAppearanceCornerFull" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/friday"
        style="?materialFilterChipStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chip_choice_fri"
        app:chipEndPadding="12dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="12dp"
        app:shapeAppearance="?shapeAppearanceCornerFull" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/saturday"
        style="?materialFilterChipStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chip_choice_sat"
        app:chipEndPadding="12dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="12dp"
        app:shapeAppearance="?shapeAppearanceCornerFull" />
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

The style applied to the chip:
<style name="Widget.Material3.Chip.Filter.WiraApp">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">?shapeAppearanceCornerFull</item>
    <item name="textEndPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="textStartPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="chipStartPadding">9.5dp</item>
    <item name="chipEndPadding">9.5dp</item>
    <item name="checkedIconEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="checkedIconVisible">false</item>
</style>

Material Version: 1.9.0

ChipGroup#checkedChipIds works fine, so i guess there might be some bug in your code. Can you add more code so we can reproduce the error?

@MiroslavHýbler I have added the styling I applied to the ChipGroup and the Chips. The overall overrides the Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar

Based on code you provided ChipGroup#checkedChipIds works as expected. Don't use daysFilter.children.map { it as Chip }.filter { it.isChecked } because it refers to View.isChecked which is not used by Chip.
Some of your Chips has set android:checkable="false" so you can't check them.
With this code i was able to read all checked chips (expects the uncheckable ones) also with app:singleSelection="false".
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val chipgroup: ChipGroup = findViewById(R.id.days_filter)
        //Added button to your layout so i can read selected chips on click
        findViewById<View>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            val list = chipgroup.checkedChipIds
            Log.d("CHIPS", "Checked items: $list")
        }
    }
}

If you are still getting empty list, i believe there is some bug in your code where you are trying to read selected chips. Use ChipGroup#checkedChipIds and check that you are trying to get checkedChipIds in right place in your code.
I am using material version 1.11.0.
